# Undefined index: user_id. Where, user_id is session variable

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am trying to register user. After registering user is direct log on. So basically I want to start session after immediately registering.

But I am unable to do this because session variable does not set! It gives me headache :(

Please Help Me..

Here code of inserting into users table:

```
// Add register user 
if(isset($_POST["register_btn"]))
 {
    extract(array_map("test_input", $_POST));
    $md5pass=md5($password);

    $m->set_data('full_name',$full_name);
    $m->set_data('gender',$gender);
    $m->set_data('email',$email); 
    $m->set_data('mobile',$mobile);
    $m->set_data('password',$md5pass);
    $m->set_data('created_date',$date);
    $m->set_data('updated_date',$date);

    $a1= array ('role_id'=> 2,
                'full_name'=> $m->get_data('full_name'),
                'gender'=> $m->get_data('gender'),
                'email'=> $m->get_data('email'),
                'mobile'=> $m->get_data('mobile'),
                'password'=> $m->get_data('password'),
                'created_date' => $m->get_data('created_date'),
                'updated_date' => $m->get_data('updated_date'));

    $last_auto_id=$d->last_auto_id("users");
    $res=mysqli_fetch_array($last_auto_id);
    $user_id=$res['Auto_increment'];

    // inserting into users table
    $insert=$d->insert('users',$a1);

    if($insert>0)
    {
        // I am starting session here
        $_SESSION['user_id']=$user_id;
        header("location:account.php?msg=Your account has been created.");
    }
    else {
        header("location:account.php?msg=Error.");
    }
 }
```

Now if I try to print $_SESSION['user_id'] in below code:

```
<?php
    extract(array_map("test_input", $_GET));
    if(isset($msg)) {
        echo $msg . "<br/>";
        echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['user_id'] ;
    }
?>
```

It gives me output:

> Your account has been created.
>
> Notice: Undefined index: user_id in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\maxosale_client\account.php on line 30 Welcome,

I written session_start() in header and included in this above code so that's not the problem.

So here's my problem please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the problem. I wasn't starting my session in the page where I'm inserting data into users table.

Now I put session_start();

And it runs perfectly fine.

Here code:

```
session_start();
// Add register user 
if(isset($_POST["register_btn"]))
{
extract(array_map("test_input", $_POST));
$md5pass=md5($password);

$m->set_data('full_name',$full_name);
$m->set_data('gender',$gender);
$m->set_data('email',$email); 
$m->set_data('mobile',$mobile);
$m->set_data('password',$md5pass);
$m->set_data('created_date',$date);
$m->set_data('updated_date',$date);

$a1= array ('role_id'=> 2,
            'full_name'=> $m->get_data('full_name'),
            'gender'=> $m->get_data('gender'),
            'email'=> $m->get_data('email'),
            'mobile'=> $m->get_data('mobile'),
            'password'=> $m->get_data('password'),
            'created_date' => $m->get_data('created_date'),
            'updated_date' => $m->get_data('updated_date'));

$last_auto_id=$d->last_auto_id("users");
$res=mysqli_fetch_array($last_auto_id);
$user_id=$res['Auto_increment'];

// inserting into users table
$insert=$d->insert('users',$a1);

if($insert>0)
{
    // I am starting session here
    $_SESSION['user_id']=$user_id;
    header("location:account.php?msg=Your account has been created.");
}
else {
    header("location:account.php?msg=Error.");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the notice, are you able to see `$_SESSION['user_id']` value? If so, try this:

```
extract(array_map("test_input", $_GET));
if(isset($msg)) {
    echo $msg . "<br/>";
    $user_id = isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? trim($_SESSION['user_id']) : '';
    echo "Welcome, " . $user_id ;
}
```

If you are not able to see `$_SESSION['user_id']` value after that notice then there is some problem with session handling. You see notices / warnings / errors based on your php error_reporting setting at code or php.ini file settings.

Comment: I'm not able to **see/get value** of `$_SESSION['user_id']` variable in other page, because session variable doesn't created. That's my main problem.

Answer (score 0):

If some sort of tricks are not working you can add
    `error_reporting(0);`
before initializing session variables and you will get rid of it.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using session_start() before using any $_SESSION variables.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    extract(array_map("test_input", $_GET));
    if(isset($msg)) {
        echo $msg . "<br/>";
        echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['user_id'] ;
    }
?>
```